# Check for value of multiple properties only if they exist in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, conditional-statements, cypher

I have nodes of type x with some properties.
I am trying to form a query that checks if a given set of properties exist in x, and if they do, compare each them with a value and then return the relevant node. The psuedo code would be something like this:-

```
match(x)
if exist(x.a, x.b)
   then if(x.a==1 and x.b==2)
         return x
else if exist(x.a)
   then if(x.a==1)
         return x
else if exist(x.b)
   then if(x.b==1)
         return x
```

I have tried :-

```
MATCH (x) WHERE exists(x.a) and ('high' IN (x.a)) and exists(x.b) and ('high' IN (x.b)) RETURN x
```

and:-

```
match(x) where x.a='high' and x.b='high' return x
```

But the problem with both these queries is that if, say 'a' is not a property in x and 'b' is, it returns null without giving a result based on at least the value of 'b'. I am assuming that is because of the and clause, but I cant find an alternative.
I am using neo4j 3.1.3

Comment: You could possible work with UNIONs, linking together the three different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UNION operator will help out in this case, making the query something like this:-

```
match(x) where x.a='high' return x union match(x) where x.b='high' return x
```

Got the idea from [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7950075/tom-geudens)'s answer above!

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

```
CREATE (:X {a: "first a"})
CREATE (:X {a: "second a", b: "first b"})
CREATE (:X {b: "second b"})

MATCH (x:X)
WHERE exists(x.a)
AND exists (x.b)
AND <any other conditions>
RETURN x
UNION 
MATCH (x:X)
WHERE exists(x.a)
AND NOT exists (x.b)
AND <any other conditions>
RETURN x
UNION 
MATCH (x:X)
WHERE NOT exists(x.a)
AND exists (x.b)
AND <any other conditions>
RETURN x;
```

Since the three cases return the same thing you can specify the three cases and UNION them together.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: So UNION certainly seems to be the way to go about it. Only edit being that I need not check for exists when using union.
So the query will be something like this:-

match(x)
where x.a='high'
return x
union
match(x)
where x.b='high'
return x

Thanks!